# Find which files has repetitive characters after a string match

Tags: linux

I have 100 files containing strings after P1,P2,P3 like this -

```
P1
AJFNAJFNJASCLMAAKSNCLKJAXCJKAJCAMSAMNCM

P2
AKJFKJASKANSKNCNAKSNCKANSKC

P3
ADAJSDKJANDKNNANDNKNAKNDADNAMNDANDMNAD
```

Out of the 100 files, some of them might have repetitive 'N' characters. For example like in P2 -

```
P1
SFKJANKCNAKCAJSCBAJCJACJNAJKSNC

P2
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN

P3
AKJSCBAJSBCKJASCKJASKJCKASNCKJANSKCJNASJ
```

I need to find which files has only the repetitive 'N' in the line after P2. Here I am not worried about the any occurence of 'N' in P1 or P3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Ezl 'P2[[:space:]]+[N]{2,}[[:space:]]+' files*
```

Enable regular expression interpretation in grep (-E). Consume the file as a single line (-z) Print on the file names with -l

Search for P2, one or more spaces, N at least two times, followed by one or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep twice:

```
grep -A 1 P2 | grep NN
```

The -A 1 greps all lines with P2 and the 1 line after.
Piping that to grep NN finds consecutive lines having P2 and NN